Unable to split meshes
I am unable to select those single meshes. Once I click on one of them all the parts are selected together. I tried selecting one in Edit Mode and then use split or separate (also clear parents) but they don't split.
Any idea about what I should do to be able to split/unlink those meshes?


I'm unfamiliar with KIT OPS but in your screenshot I see that you have 'Group Mode' enabled, which might have something to do with it. If not, then I would suggest to provide more information about what kind of addons you're using and how you created the meshes in question. This will help in finding an answer to this issue.

Thanks a lot, when I dactivate the group mode is working normally :)
